# Create user in Active Directory using node.js

Tags: node.js, active-directory

I need to create a user in `Active Directory` with `node.js`. I found [this library](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory), but this seems to only get information out of AD and is not able to create Objects, e.g. a user.

I have never worked with AD before and have less to no knowledge about it. May someone help me how I can realize this with `node.js` (TypeScript)?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the Graph REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

This needs an auth token to use the API above which you can get using this one https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/client-credentials-sample.js

Comment: I believe this only works in AAD not in AD. Graph API is for cloud users. OP did not mention Azure AD.